# PHP cannot find tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a little problem to execute a tensorflow program via php. 
I want to execute the tensorflow based program "Luminoth".
Here is my executed python file script.py:

`import subprocess
subprocess.call(["sudo", "python", "/usr/local/bin/lumi", "predict", "/var/www/html/image1.jpg", "--checkpoint", "instruments", "-f", "/var/www/html/objects.json", "-d", "/var/www/html/"])`

when I do this the php echo says:

`blubstdout : string(0) "" stderr : string(171) "Luminoth requires a TensorFlow >= 1.5 installation. Depending on your use case, you should install either`tensorflow`or`tensorflow-gpu`packages manually or via PyPI. " done`

Its the same when I use a shell script script.sh instead the script.py

`#!/bin/bash 
/usr/local/bin/lumi predict /var/www/html/pictures/image1.jpg  --checkpoint instruments /var/www/html//pictures/predictions/objects.json -d /var/www/html/pictures/predictions/`

in the python script i tried to set import `import tensorflow` or `import tensorflow as tf` in front. Then the echo is:

`blubstdout : string(0) "" stderr : string(384) "Traceback (most recent call last): File "script.py", line 1, in import tensorflow File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in from tensorflow.python import * File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 47, in import numpy as np ImportError: No module named numpy " done`

When i add `import numpy` it says:

`blubstdout : string(0) "" stderr : string(127) "Traceback (most recent call last): File "script.py", line 1, in import numpy ImportError: No module named numpy " done`

but i installed numpy before with 
`sudo apt-get install python3-numpy`

Do you have any ideas to solve this problem?

Thank you very much and have a good day!

Comment: All of these are in python, not sure why you include PHP in your question.

Comment: Are you sure you run PHP, not Python?

Comment: oh sry. i execute the py file in php with shell_exec("script.py")

Comment: Try importing numpy using a [full path](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/How-to-import-a-Python-module-given-the-full-path)